# Call ViewBag in Jquery to get the value from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am calling `ViewBag.DeliveryDatebySupplier` to update my textbox or just to alert. The value was always `null`. But when I debug and check the `ViewBag` in controller it has the date value.

**Controller**

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
{
    string dt = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DeliveryDt"].ToString();
    DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
    dt =  myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ViewBag.DeliveryDatebySupplier = dt.ToString();
    //Session["NewDeliveryDate"] = dt.ToString();                    
}
```

**Jquery**

```
function getDeliveryDateBySupplier() {
    var _storeID = $('#ddlStoreID :selected').val();
    var _SupplierID = $('#ddlSupplier :selected').val();

    var url = "@Url.Content("~/Home/DeliveryDatebySupplier")";

    $.ajax({
        data: {
             StoreID: _storeID,
             SupplierID: _SupplierID
        },
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            var newDeliveryDate = '@ViewBag.DeliveryDatebySupplier';
            alert(newDeliveryDate);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert("Error getDeliveryDateBySupplier()");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the action called **DeliveryDatebySupplier** in the **HomeController** is the method to set **ViewBag.DeliveryDatebySupplier**, then this will not work unfortunately.

The script will be generated when the full page was generated and at that time, the value would not have been set yet.

I would advise, rather than using the viewbag, return the value when DeliveryDatebySupplier is called in your script.

Controller will be something like this then

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
    string dt = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DeliveryDt"].ToString();
    DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
    dt =  myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return new JsonResult
    {
        data = new
        {
            DeliveryDatebySupplier = dt.ToString()
        }
    };                     
    }
```

and jquery would change to something like this

```
success: function (data) {
 if (data) {
    var newDeliveryDate = data.DeliveryDatebySupplier
    alert(newDeliveryDate);
}
else {
    //Error
}
},
```